# Under sampling or Over Sampling the dataset using Weka

Tags: weka

Hi I'm using Weka framework to perform a data mining task. My dataset is highly imbalances. Once class consists of 1463 labels and other consists of 104. If I under sample the higher number of class becomes into 104 and the total number of variables will become 208. I feel like this is an information loss.

What will be the most suitable option to use in such cases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try reweighting using the ClassBalancer filter. 
[image]

This will keep all your instances, just reweight them.